# Text data to a category

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have created a key with the disease name in column A and the Category in column B in worksheet1. in worksheet2 I have a list of cases (1-31,000) with the disease they had. How can I match the diseases the cases have with the category of that disease from worksheet1? All the columns are text based.

This is an example table of disease categorisations
[image]

And this is a list of diseases that I need to categories

[image]

Thanks for the help in adavance

Comment: Research  ```VLOOKUP```.

Comment: Could you provide a sample table about your problem? There are several functions you can use to match data in Excel.

Comment: Try using a pivot table.  Without seeing an anononamised data set it's hard to imagine if it can or can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

In table A, define a Range "cat_list" as $A$2:$B$31001, meaning that includes all actual values of both columns, DON'T include header-names in this range. Make absolute reference by putting $ as above.

In table B, if Final Diagnosis List is in Column A, put this formula in column B2

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'E:\myData\cat_file.xlsx'!cat_list,2,0)
```

here E:\myData is the location where File A is saved, and put its name in place of cat_file. If both the tables are in different sheets of same excel file, then 'E:\myData\cat_file.xlsx'! part can be skipped.

copy this formula up to the lowermost cell having data in Table B.

You will get the category in Column B in Table B, wherever it matches 100%.

In table A, there is a "cattle tick", but in table B there is a "cattle tick-neighbor", they will not match so its category will not come next to it.